# vim JavaScript Indent plugin - what are the commands?

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I'm interested in using the [JavaScript Indent plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081), but the vim script  [page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081) only describes how to install the plugin.

Is there a help file for the plugin?  How do I use it?

I have tried to google for some help on using it but the best I have found so far is generic advice on [Fix_indentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_indentation).  Is there more to the JavaScript Indent plugin than is described in the Fix_indentation page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indent plugin sets the `'indentexpr'` option; if it's properly installed (i.e. under `~/.vim/indent/javascript.vim`, and listed under `:scriptnames` after editing a JavaScript file), it should work out of the box.

You can verify with

```
:verbose setlocal indentexpr?
SetJsIndent(v:lnum)
```